# A question about interfaces that run on Java but not in C#

Tags: java, c#, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a service layer structure works on Java without any error. But when I try it on C# it's not working as I expected. I have a common service interface `IService` which has a method `Update` that returns another interface `IUpdateResult`. And I have a custom service interface `IAService` like below.

```cs
public interface IService 
{
    IUpdateResult Update();
}

public interface IAService : IService 
{     

}
```

And finally I have a `UpdateResult` class which implements `IUpdateResult`.

```
public class UpdateResult : IUpdateResult
{
}
```

I am implementing custom service class like below and it does not allow me to do this.

```cs
public class AService : IAService
{
    public UpdateResult Update()
    {
        // bla bla
    }
}
```

As I mentioned it's working on Java the way I want. Why does C# give me error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's planned to work in C# 9: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/ scroll to the bottom

Comment: _"It's planned for C# 9"_ oh no ... that was one thing why I preferred C# over Java :(

Comment: @Fildor Why don't you like the idea of covariant returns?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have to admit that it's not really rational. When I coded in Java, there just were some occasions, where this started confusion among devs and recurring discussions about interfaces. There are pros and cons, I get that. It's just my personal thing that I find those pros not very convincing. To me it's like giving up clear, _sharply defined_ interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I mentioned it's working on Java the way I want. Why does C# give me error?

Because Java and C# are different languages, designed by different teams of people. :)

Don't worry, as the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258363/a-question-about-interfaces-that-run-on-java-but-not-in-c-sharp#comment113628944_64258363) said, [this feature is planned for C# 9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/).

For now, you can use an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```
public class AService : IAService
{
    public UpdateResult Update()
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    IUpdateResult IService.Update() { return Update(); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I am really appreciated